# What is the best way to store data in Python?

Tags: python, database, authentication, local-storage

I'm creating a Skype bot for a group of friends, and I want to be able to have a somewhat login system for text-based games and storing information such as usernames, high scores, notes, friends list, messages, etc.

I was thinking of storing it in a text file named after the person's handle on Skype, however, I was wondering if there was a better way of doing it. Such as XML files.

I'd like to avoid SQL servers, and it's not like they're storing passwords so encryption won't be that much of a big deal. (I'd prefer local file storage. Something easily editable and delete-able)

I want to enable commands such as !note and !friends and !addfriend and !highscore and so on, but I need a method to save that information.

Comment: IIRC Python still comes with SQLite so you can use that. However, it really depends on what you need. Possibly with https://github.com/coleifer/peewee.

Comment: I was hoping something on the lighter side. (Simpler). Ex: XML files, or JSON files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you considered `pickle`? It can store python objects (any object) to files so you can just load and use them.

```
import pickle

# Saving
data = [1,2,3,4]
pickle.dump(data, open("d:/temp/test.pkl","wb"))

# Loading
load = pickle.load(open("d:/temp/test.pkl","rb"))
```

For more info, read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/pickle.html#module-pickle)

(Another option is the `json` module which serializes to json. It is used in a similar way, but can only save dictionaries, lists, strings and integers)

Comment: Even though `pickle` can serialize more objects, `json` is safer. If you can convert all you data into dictionaries and lists, I'd use `json`

Comment: Also JSON manipulation is a more transferrable skill used across many languages and situations.