# How to store player data in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm creating a mini-game bot in discord.py. One of the things I remembered that I wanted in the design is player profiles. How can I approach this? How can I store player data in discord.py? I'm not new to file I/O but I'm not that experienced in it either, so that's something to keep in mind :)

I understand that this question is a little broad and vague, but I didn't know how to ask this in any other way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to store data, this isn't really a discord.py specific question. If you're storing a small amount of data you could use a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#dict). If you do use a dict the data will be lost when the python program is terminated.

You could also use a database such as [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) or SQLite. This is better if you're storing large data and the data will be stored until you delete it.

There are many ways to store data in python, here are some lists to help you.

[What is the best way to store data in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028809/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-data-in-python)

https://realpython.com/storing-images-in-python/

Comment: Thanks so much! I guess I tagged it as discord.py because I'm doing this for a bot. But again, thank you!